# Deal-killing surprise?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

Origin :   Communicate company’s positions completely and accurately to the Customer to avoid deal-killing surprises once Legal is engaged to support negotiations.

Q: what does "deal-killing" mean?

Comment: From what I understand, it means that once "Legal" is engaged to support negotiations (referring to the deals in danger of being "killed", I guess), [whoever this message is directed toward] will be able to communicate the company's positions to the "Customer" in such a way that surprises **_which would in some way dissuade or discontinue the deal_** will be avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *deal* in business is a negotiated transaction, here between the company and one its customers.  It seems here that company officials make preliminary arrangements with the customer, and when these are satisfactory, the company's legal department becomes involved to draw up the final contract.  If company officials haven't been completely clear about the terms of the deal before the legal department gets involved, the customer may have some misunderstandings about the contract.  If so, they may well be unpleasantly surprised when the legal department explains things.  If the surprise is unpleasant enough, the customer may decline to do business with the company.  Refusing to go ahead with the contract is called "killing the deal."

In that case, not only has the company wasted its time on a business venture that wasn't concluded, they have angered a potential customer who isn't likely to come back to do business but who is likely to tell others about the unpleasant (from their point of view) experience.

Answer (score 0):

Deal-killing means a term or condition that is totally and absolutely unacceptable to one of the parties involved.

Could be for any reason.
A baseball contract could allow a player to be traded anywhere at any time. If a player felt strongly enough, wording like that in a contract is a deal-killer, or not having a no-trade clause in the final contract could be the deal killer.

It is frustrating and unproductive if there are terms or conditions that arise after a lot of work. A company may have and age restriction, or a citizenship restriction, or a relocation requirement that the company wants to clear up early because they are deal-killers.